# how can i pass this query to my controller in codeigniter and to use this in my foreach in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
function getAllReferrals(){

$sql = "(SELECT r.referral_date,c.lastname,c.middlename,c.firstname,c.gender,r.presenting_problem,e.employee_nickname 
    AS nickname FROM CLIENT c INNER JOIN referral1 r ON c.referral_id = r.referral1_id INNER JOIN assign_psychotherapist ap 
    ON ap.a_referral_id = c.referral_id INNER JOIN employee e ON ap.a_psychotherapist_id = e.empid WHERE r.referral_status ='Assigned' 
    OR r.referral_status ='Accepted' ORDER BY referral_date DESC ) UNION ALL (SELECT r.referral_date,c.lastname,c.middlename,c.firstname,
    c.gender,r.presenting_problem,v.volunteer_nickname AS nickname FROM CLIENT c INNER JOIN referral1 r ON c.referral_id = r.referral1_id 
    INNER JOIN assignvolunteer av ON av.Vreferralid = c.referral_id INNER JOIN volunteer v ON av.Vvolunteerid = v.volid 
    WHERE r.referral_status ='Assigned' OR r.referral_status ='Accepted' ORDER BY referral_date DESC )";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->result();
}else{
    return NULL;
}
```

}

> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() -> having this error

Comment: Use this function inside your model, than in controller load this model and use this function and return its result to array varaible and assign it to any view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the given information let me answer the question.

`how can i pass this query to my controller in CodeIgniter`

Understand that query isn't passed to the controller from the model but what's passed is data. what you have to do is returned the data from model to controller and set the data into the `$data` variable in the controller which is then passed to the view.

Adding more you are getting above error because there is no data(result array is empty) in the array. Make sure that you query returns array of data as well. Try executing it manually in MySQL and see the result.

Try `result_array()` which returns the query result as a pure array, or an empty array when no result is produced.

[Read more](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Comment: i tried to use the result_array() is still giving me empty array

Comment: that's because your query returns no data

Comment: sorry about that sir i fixed it already. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

First try execute your query  manuly, and check get any result you can try your program. `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() -> having this error` this type of error occurred your result array may be empty.

Answer (score 0):

first create a model . and paste this code on model like your model name is ex_model.php

```
    function getAllReferrals(){

$sql = "(SELECT r.referral_date,c.lastname,c.middlename,c.firstname,c.gender,r.presenting_problem,e.employee_nickname 
    AS nickname FROM CLIENT c INNER JOIN referral1 r ON c.referral_id = r.referral1_id INNER JOIN assign_psychotherapist ap 
    ON ap.a_referral_id = c.referral_id INNER JOIN employee e ON ap.a_psychotherapist_id = e.empid WHERE r.referral_status ='Assigned' 
    OR r.referral_status ='Accepted' ORDER BY referral_date DESC ) UNION ALL (SELECT r.referral_date,c.lastname,c.middlename,c.firstname,
    c.gender,r.presenting_problem,v.volunteer_nickname AS nickname FROM CLIENT c INNER JOIN referral1 r ON c.referral_id = r.referral1_id 
    INNER JOIN assignvolunteer av ON av.Vreferralid = c.referral_id INNER JOIN volunteer v ON av.Vvolunteerid = v.volid 
    WHERE r.referral_status ='Assigned' OR r.referral_status ='Accepted' ORDER BY referral_date DESC )";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->result();
}else{
    return NULL;
}
```

and create controller and get add this code like

```
<?php
public function reffers(){

$this->load->model('ex_model');
$data['refferdata'] = $this->ex_model->getAllReferrals();
$this->load->view('reffer');
}
?>
```

now create a view name reffer.php and get all data from foreach loop like

```
<?php

foreach($refferdata as $r)
{
echo $r->r.referral_date.<br>;
echo $r->c.lastname.<br>;

// and so on like this in view
}

?>
```